# Calculating 'acceptable' % change month over month

Tags: probability, descriptive-statistics

We are tracking a set of monthly business metrics (some are absolute numbers and some are %). For each metric, we want to find a range of variations that tells us if the current month's performance is as expected or warannts a callout. We are expecting that if we are not deploying a major change in the technology, a metric should fall in the range. There might be some seasonality to the data. Ranges should be given relevant to most recent month.

My first idea is to analyse the data, see if they follow some kind of distribution and use the standard deviation to create the band. Another approach could be to remove the outliers and look at a moving average of last x months.

I am not sure how to capture the seasonality of data, e.g. we are expecting much higher variations in holiday season.

What would be your suggestions to approach the problem and if you can recommend a resource to read more about the topic?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, a lot depends on how much data you have. In principle, you could just analyze each month separately...but how many "July's" do you have?  If you are working with very limited data, best first step is just to see if the data looks normal.  If that fails (say, because it's obvious that ever winter month is a bad outlier in this system) then you'll have to model the distribution somehow.  This would be more of a business call than a mathematical one.

Comment: We have around two years of data so around 20-24 data points.

Comment: Right.  So, like two Julys.  $24$ data points is extremely small.  Maybe you are lucky and those points really do look normally distributed...but I have never seen real world business data that didn't have some sensitivity to externalities.  I expect you are going to have to model what you want based on what you know about the business.  Not a math problem.

Comment: Thanks - can you propose any methods to try out on the data? Or moving average/st dev is a way to go?

Comment: As I say, with such limited data you are going to need to fall back on your understanding of the business.  Draw what you think is the right shape for the data and use the (scarce) data to calibrate that.  Don't expect much.  Especially if the data is recent (business externalities have, of course, been terrible lately).

Comment: Holt-Winters seasonality method is a pretty simple way to capture seasonality, trend, and level. AKA triple exponential smoothing and can be done in Excel